# Emacs newline-and-indent in scala-mode

Tags: emacs, scala

I have `(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)` in my .emacs which works fine in all modes but scala-mode(the newest, revision 19295 from svn).

What do I need to change to get it working?

Comment: When I press the Enter key the cursor moves to the beginning of the next line, in other modes it moves to the next line and automatically indents the proper amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'scala-mode-hook
      (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'reindent-then-newline-and-indent)))
```

The above somewhat fixes the problem.  It now indents the line correctly after pressing Enter once, but still doesn't work if there is a blank line above the newline.

Answer (score 1):

In scala-mode, "RET" is bound to scala-newline by default, and this overrides the global key binding set with `global-set-key`, hence the need for the hook specific to scala-mode. Consider using:

```
(add-hook 'scala-mode-hook
      (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))
```

instead of:

```
(add-hook 'scala-mode-hook
      (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'reindent-then-newline-and-indent)))
```

If you don't want Emacs to change your indentation after leaving a line.